# How to stop a flex video from playing on load

Tags: html, css, video, modal-dialog

I currently have a flex video on my page that starts playing when the page is loaded.

How do I stop it from playing automatically?

```
     <div class="flex-video">
            <iframe width="300" height="300" src="video.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you embed your own video using iFrame then it will just play automatically. What you can do is to use a video player. You can also use the html video tag like this:

```
    <video controls>
       <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    </video>
```

Comment: Coolies. Please mark it as the correct answer to close this question. Thanks.